4.1 Any way to turn off UV temporarily?
Blender 4.1, Fedora 40 Linux, nvidia 3080 GPU.  I made a nice UV image with surface coloring for my mesh object.  Now I would like to temporarily turn off the UV while I work on other things, in this case specifically subsurface scattering.  So far I have not been able to find a way to do this.  For example, Object Data Properties > UV Maps shows that the UV is enabled for rendering, but clicking the camera image changes nothing.  I couldn't find any switch in the UV editor that didn't look like a permanent change.  All I want to do is turn off the UV temporarily without changing it.  Is there a way to do that?

A UV map is a dictionary that translates 3D coordinates into 2D coordinates. To turn it off simply don't use it. You're probably in some specific view mode, that you want to leave, but it's hard to figure it out without any screenshots.

one idea is to set the object's Viewport Display param from textured or solid to Wire:


NOTE TO SELF:  why doesn't "Solid" simply show the Shading mode to the solid Color set in the color chooser in the same panel?  Hmmm...
Alternately set your viewport mode to Solid, but this would change all objects from textured to solid.

